# Default owner and setting sticky bit by default

Tags: access-control-list, rhel5, setfacl

I have a RHEL 5.5 server and want to set up some specific security for a directory:

Please note that I am not asking how to do this one time... that has already been done.

1. I want all new directories created to have the sticky bit set so only the owner can delete the folder  (I have already set it on all the existing folders but newly created ones do not inherit it - This is where the issue lies).
2. I want the default owner of all subdirectories and files to be a specific user - no matter who creates it.

I've searched and haven't found an implementation that allows for this so maybe it just isn't possible without setting a cron to go in and change the permissions?

I have already used setfacl to give a default group the rwx permissions needed
I have already set the Group ID  (SGID)
As mentioned, I have already set the sticky bit on existing folders

Comment: How are the files being written?  Locally?  Or via samba or nfs?

Comment: Both - plus Helios - a third-party app for Macs to connect

Answer (score 0):

The owner is always the creating user. I know of no mechanism with traditional permissions or ACLs to change that. (The story is different for the owning group.)

Neither does any mechanism exist to inherit the sticky bit.

By the way, what is your workflow/use case? It seems strange that users should be able to create files and dirs which they can not remove any more (because it would belong to someone else already).